# Ada - Sensible code structure for SHA3 implementation

Tags: ada

I'm using the SHA3 specification as a learning example for the Ada programming language.

The spec contains a family of data structures call Permutations, there are seven of these and they differ only by being able to handle different amounts of data.  They contain a three-dimensional "State Array" where the first two dimensions are always **mod 5** and the third dimension is **mod N**, where N is limited to these few values: 25, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800 and 1600.

I'd normally think to use generics to make the distinction between each package variation, but the difference is a number, and not a type.

How might I sensibly design my package / record types?

The only way I can think of doing this is to simply make a set of explicit types...

```
package Perm_25 is...
package Perm_50 is...
package Perm_100 is...
package Perm_200 is...
package Perm_400 is...
package Perm_800 is...
package Perm_1600 is...
```

Clearly that is nonsensical because it's laborious and requires me to duplicate a lot of code, which would invite inconsistencies.

Also I'm not convinced that OOP would help here because the types really aren't different apart from some array dimensions.

How should I approach this problem?

---

EDIT: Thanks to user @flyx for the tip to use a Static_Predicate subtype and a discriminated record type.  Using that advice I have managed to get the following code to compile...

```
package body SHA3 is

  subtype Perm_w_Coeff_Type is Positive
    with Static_Predicate
      => Perm_w_Coeff_Type in 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32 | 64;

  subtype Perm_l_Coeff_Type is Natural range 0 .. 6;

  type State_Array_Type is array (Natural range <>, Natural range <>, Natural range <>) of Boolean;

  -- (see FIPS202 section 3)
  type KECCAK_p_Permutation (bPW : b_Permutation_Width; numRounds : Positive; W_Coeff : Perm_w_Coeff_Type) is
    record
      b : b_Permutation_Width := bPW;


      -- initialise w based on a lookup table using b as its index
      -- (see FIPS202 section 3.1, table 1)
      w : Perm_w_Coeff_Type := (
          case bPW is
            when 25 => 1,
            when 50 => 2,
            when 100 => 4,
            when 200 => 8,
            when 400 => 16,
            when 800 => 32,
            when 1600 => 64
            );

      -- initialise l based on a lookup table using b as its index
      -- (see FIPS202 section 3.1, table 1)
      l : Perm_l_Coeff_Type := (
          case bPW is
            when 25 => 0,
            when 50 => 1,
            when 100 => 2,
            when 200 => 3,
            when 400 => 4,
            when 800 => 5,
            when 1600 => 6
            );

      n_sub_r : Positive := numRounds;

      State_Array : State_Array_Type (0 .. 4, 0 .. 4, 0 .. W_Coeff);
    end record;


  procedure Run is
  begin
    null;
  end Run;


end SHA3;
```

Comment: Ada has no problems making a package generic on a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
subtype Third_Dimension_Type is Natural with
  Static_Predicate => Third_Dimension_Type in 25 | 50 | 100 | 200 | 400 | 800 | 1600;
```

I don't know what you mean by „the first two dimensions are always mod 5“, but assuming you mean they have 5 entries, the resulting data type would the be something like:

```
type Permutation (Third_Dimension : Third_Dimension_Type) is record
   State : array (1..5, 1..5, 1..Third_Dimension) of Item_Type;
end record;
```

Note that you cannot specify an array type that takes two discrete ranges and one indefinite range (e.g. `Third_Dimension_Type range <>`), so you need to use a discriminated record instead.

Comment: This looks promising.  Seems that my version of gnat (4.4.7) doesn't like the syntax, so I'll try this in a few hours on my other PC which has the latest gnat 7.4.0 (with 2012 support) installed on it.

Comment: `Static_Predicate` is Ada 2012. For earlier Ada versions, you'd just declare `Third_Dimension_Type` as `Natural` and can't enforce it to only hold one of the valid values.

Comment: It worked!... kind of :) now I have a whole bunch of other syntactical nightmares to fathom out.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  Cheers.

Comment: p.s. I've updated the question with the code resulting from your advice.  It's not close to finished yet but it mostly illustrates what I wanted to do.  I think the next thing for me to do is figure out how to pass in a single record (instead of three separate fields) that makes the dimension sizes a bit easier to understand.

Comment: You'd have to use an `access` type in the discriminant to have everything in a single value. I'd advice against `w` and `l` being parts of the record; they seem to be functions on `b_Permutation_Width` and should be implemented as such. Default values in the record can be overridden which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: I am curious; when you make an array with one or more dimensions with a static_predicate, is a spare array created with only those elements you can access? In this case, does that dimension have a size of 1600 or 7 in the array?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn The LRM says „A one-dimensional array has a distinct component for each possible index value.“ however that does not tell us much as it does not describe the memory layout (it can have the size of 1600 components while only using 7 slots in it). You can try doing `for My_Array'Size use Component'Size * 7;` and see if your compiler likes it, or for just testing what the compiler does, write test code that outputs the `'Size` of an object of that array.

Comment: The code you posted in your answer is rejected by gnat 20.2 with `anonymous arrays not allowed as components`.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Well if you want to figure it out in detail, you can post a new question containing your code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gone for the detail of your question, but I'm answering something that caught my eye: you say you can't use generics because the parameter that changes isn't a type. However, you can parameterize generics with values (not saying that's the best approach in this case, but that you can do it):

```
generic
   Foo : Integer := 5; -- Or any other type.
package Bar is ...
```